# Asp.net DropDownlist with headers

Tags: asp.net

I need to display drop down list with headers

values are retriving from database
i need to  display like

**Maharashtra**

- Mumbai
- Nasik
- Pune

**UttarPradesh**

- Lucknow
- Meerut
- Noida
- Ghaziabad

**Uttrakhand**

- Dehradun
- Rishikesh
- Haridwar

Answer (score 0):

`<asp:DropDownList>` does not directly support the use of `<optgroup>`. You will need to ether implement your own control or use an adapter. Here is one such example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15505/ASP-NET-DropDownList-with-OptionGroup-support

Another option is to use only `<option>` elements, but instead add fake-indent by adding extra (visible) whitespace prefixed to the `Text` of each `ListItem`.